# I put my repo on github but all my tags are gone

Tags: tags, github

I put my repo on github but when I go to tags they are not there. I expect to see tags like '1.1', '1.0', etc that I used to mark my releases. Is it a GitHub issue or does git normally do that? All my code and history is there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly push your tags to the remote (GitHub) repo

```
git push --tags origin
```

From [`git push` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push):

```
--tags
```

> All refs under `refs/tags` are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line.

See also "[tagging](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/03/tagging.html)" or the [GitHub help on pushing](http://help.github.com/remotes/#pushing):

> **Pushing tags**
>
> By default, push will only send the ref you specify.
>
> - To push a single tag you can simply use **`git push REMOTENAME TAGNAME`**.
> - To push all tags while pushing another branch, you can use **`git push REMOTENAME BRANCHNAME --tags`**.

Comment: Hi I just wanted to leave another comment here to let you know that I've been learning git and I've done a lot of google searches that seem to inevitably lead to SO threads that you have answered. I've read a lot them and they've been very helpful. Thanks very much for all the time you put into your answers.

Comment: @test: you are welcome :) I have been learning a lot by answering those questions. I am sure you have read answers from other valuable contributors too, like those listed at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers: they actually know more about Git than I do!